# Good Zend Framework example apps to learn from

Tags: php, zend-framework, open-source

Do you know of any open-source Zend Framework applications besides Magento that show in a good OOP-way how to develop big apps with Zend Framework?

My problem right now is, that I'm pretty good at PHP and OOP, but I don't have enough knowledge of the Zend Framework and how things should be solved in it.

So do you know any good applications that showcase best-practices for ZF?

Thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have a look at:

- JotBug (from 2009): http://www.ohloh.net/p/jotbug ([zip file of code](http://akrabat.com/wp-content/uploads/jotbug.zip))
- Pastebin: http://github.com/weierophinney/pastebin/
- 'ZF 1.8 Web Application Development' code: http://code.google.com/p/zendframeworkstorefront/
- Enygma's Ext-JS with ZF example app: https://github.com/enygma/Agile-ExtJS-ZF
- MTD issues: https://github.com/mtd/issues

Comment: Have checked these links and found JotBug most usefull, therefore I didn't found code for checks in model and code for showing error messages when some fields in HTML form didn't filled properly

Comment: None of these are working. i downloaded and tried to setup. is there any other app that i can take a look at? appreciate an early reply

Comment: Hmm.. There's the zip file attached to http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/, but that's just a "Hello World" app.

Answer (score 1):

Magento is a good example of the Zend Framework, Until you start looking at how they decided to go about templating! Wow.. wonder how late that meeting was when they decided to depart from logic and create their highly nested template components.. fun times (from a designers perspective) :)

Answer (score 0):

I've only peeked into the source of Magento (magentocommerce.com) but it has a pretty good result on the outside.

Comment: It is worth noting that Magento does not use any of the MVC components from the framework... Just parts of the library.