# Example Zend Framework Project 1.8+

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

Let me begin by saying this; I know that similar questions exist, but they are a couple years old and ZF is changing quickly.  I want a more recent example.

It has been noted a lot that the documentation on Zend Framework is lacking.  I've read a lot of it and used it to start up a few applications, but I find that it is really difficult to understand how to do things properly.  My biggest issue is where various components belong, where they should be instantiated, etc.

I am trying to follow MVC best practices, with thin controllers, fat models.  I am also trying to use the latest MVC stack including Zend_Application and the recommended Bootstrap classes.

I want to see an example site that uses best practices for the framework which can demonstrate the following components (*ideally*):

- **Zend_ACL/Zend_Auth**: how to actually use them in an application, how to fit it in to your model, etc.
- **Zend_Layout**: how to do this properly with common parts such as a menu
- **Zend_Navigation**: I mostly don't know the best practice for instantiating this.
- **Zend_Cache**: Again, where does it belong, do you use it in Controllers (probably?)
- **Zend_Db**: I want the example to use a database obviously, but I'd prefer just using ZF and not Doctrine
- **Zend_Feed**: I'm not completely sure how to make an RSS feed properly (i.e. set the content type, etc.)
- **Zend_Form**: I haven't used this yet, but I understand it is good for validating data passed into the Model.  I'd like to see this in action
- **Zend_Paginator**: Again, where do you instantiate this, Model or Controller?

I know I do not need to use everything in the framework, but I want to try to use whatever may fit my needs and I'd like to learn more about it.

So do you know of a good example that uses the Zend MVC and some or all of these components?  And one that follows a lot of best practices?  Ideally, it is using at least 1.10, but anything 1.8 or later will suffice.

Comment: Good question ;) The use-at-will architecture make the "best practice" hidde in the pile of custom setups and extending.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/794240/good-zend-framework-example-apps-to-learn-from

Comment: The problem is that there's not 1 way to do things, even if you follow "best practices". So read some books covering the subject, study some projects, read some blogs and go from there. There's a LOT of information out there, so it might help to focus on one thing at a time.

Comment: I was aware of the other question, but it was a bit old and I was hoping for newer examples since many of the links were broken.  @wimvds: I know there is not just one way, but I want to see some good examples.  I've been reading docs and various tutorials as needed but I want to look at a real project in action to see what else I can learn.  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, seems like most projects use their own "library" on top of Zend Framework with their own extra plugins.  That took me a while to figure out, but now I see that's how a lot of projects handle common things like authentication and ACL.  This is definitely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out cms systems build in ZF. One is [TomatoCMS](http://www.tomatocms.com/). The list of Projects & Applications using ZF is [here](http://framework.zend.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=14134). Zend Framework [website](http://framework.zend.com/behind-the-site) is build in ZF too.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the following resources:

- [Zend Framework manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/) (seems obvious, but it's really great and sufficient in most cases),
- Sample open source projects based on ZF, like [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) or [the other discussed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework+open-source),
- Zend Framework tag on Github (e.g. PasteBin or [ZFPlanet](https://github.com/padraic/ZFPlanet),
- Source code from Books (e.g. [StoreFront](http://code.google.com/p/zendframeworkstorefront/)).

To answer the other questions:

- Zend Cache has an action helper and application resource to make it really simple in usage,
- Zend Feed in action may be seen in ZFPlanet,
- Zend Paginator may be set up in bootstrap, using static methods.

Comment: And also don't forget about the [Zend Framework Webinars](http://www.zend.com/resources/webinars/framework).

Comment: Apparently there is a community wiki here, thanks for point that out!